# Invoke shell script by double clicking desktop (linux, ubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04

I would like to replicate a feature from a program i used to use in windows. stardock fences allowed me to hide all of the icons (i wanted to) on my desktop by double clicking, and then reveal them by double clicking again.

I believe something along these lines:

> gconftool-2 /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop --type bool --set false

from this page ([ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1761105))
, is what I am looking to do. my question then becomes:
How do I invoke a shell script by double clicking on the EMPTY desktop?

Yes, I know I can use an icon instead. I want the desktop. I don't even have any icons I have to have on the desktop... Oh well. I would think it's possible and I would like to learn how. The feature itself is not the most important, but when I came to the question of HOW and had no answer - that's a problem ;)

Comment: I'm going to call offtopic on this one. It's more systems configuration than programming. Try superuser, perhaps.

Comment: ... or http://askubuntu.com/ ?